# Identifying first occurrence after trigger event

Tags: sas, panel-data

I have a big panel dataset that looks somewhat like this:

```
data have;
   input id t a b ;
datalines;
1 1 0 0
1 2 0 0
1 3 1 0
1 4 0 0
1 5 0 1
1 6 1 0
1 7 0 0
1 8 0 0
1 9 0 0
1 10 0 1
2 1 0 0
2 2 1 0
2 3 0 0
2 4 0 0
2 5 0 1
2 6 0 1
2 7 0 1
2 8 0 1
2 9 1 0
2 10 0 1
3 1 0 0
3 2 0 0
3 3 0 0
3 4 0 0
3 5 0 0
3 6 0 0
3 7 1 0
3 8 0 0
3 9 0 0
3 10 0 0
;
run;
```

For every ID I want to record all 'trigger' events, namely when a=1 and then I need to how long it takes to the *next* occurrence of b=1. The final  output should then give me the following:

```
data want;
  input id a_no a_t b_t diff ;
datalines;
1 1 3 5 2
1 2 6 10 4
2 1 2 5 3
2 2 9 10 1
3 1 7 . .
;
run;
```

It is of course no problem to get all a=1 and b=1 events, but as it is a very big dataset with a lot of both events for every ID I am searching for an elegant and straight-forward solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Are there cases of a=1 and b=1 at the same t ? If so, what should happen ?

Comment: a=1 and b=1 can never happen at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple SQL approach that gives more or less the desired output:

```
proc sql;
create table want
  as select 
    t1.id, 
    t1.t as a_t, 
    t2.t as b_t, 
    t2.t - t1.t as diff
    from 
      have(where = (a=1)) t1 
      left join 
      have(where = (b=1)) t2
    on 
      t1.id = t2.id 
      and t2.t > t1.t
    group by t1.id, t1.t
    having diff = min(diff)
    ;
quit;
```

The only part missing is `a_no`. This sort of row-incrementing ID is quite a lot of work to generate consistently in SQL, but it's trivial with an extra data step:

```
data want;
 set want;
 by id;
 if first.id then a_no = 0;
 a_no + 1;
run;
```

Comment: That works very well! I was always struggling with proc sql a bit, so this solution did not strike me before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An elegant DATA step way can use nested DOW loops.  It's straight forward when you understand DOW loops.

```
data want(keep=id--diff);
  length id a_no a_t b_t diff 8;
  do until (last.id);                           * process each group;
    do a_no = 1 by 1 until(last.id);            * counter for each output;
      do until ( output_condition or end);      * process each triggering state change;

        SET have end=end;          * read data;
        by id;                     * setup first. last. variables for group;

        if a=1 then a_t = t;       * detect and record start of trigger state;

        output_condition = (b=1 and t > a_t > 0);  * evaluate for proper end of trigger state;
      end;

      if output_condition then do; 
        b_t = t;                     * compute remaining info at output point;
        diff = b_t - a_t;

        OUTPUT;

        a_t = .;       * reset trigger state tracking variables;
        b_t = .;
      end;
      else 
        OUTPUT;        * end of data reached without triggered output;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Note: A SQL way (not shown) can use self join within groups.

Comment: I consider myself something of a DOW-loop enthusiast, but I found this tricky to follow. 

Also, you can add `(where = (a=1 or b=1))` to your set statement.

Comment: One benefit of deep DOW loop processing is that a single pass of the source data set occurs.  Would be interesting to find out the 'nature' of data where performance consideration tips from SQL (requiring join) to DOW.